# Z-Index on Product Zoom Plugin Hides woocommerce options

Tags: html, css, wordpress, e-commerce

I know this is a rather simple z-index issue as I have been studying it for the past two days for a few hours each day but still can't seem to get to the bottom of this.

Every time you zoom in on any product pictures on my website, the zoom window goes under the options dropdown menus. I have tried changing both the z-index of the dropdowns as well as the zoom window without any luck. If anyone could have a look and point me in the right direction that would be great. Heres a link

http://breakwatersurfcompany.com/shop/obey-womens-89-wreath-crop-tee/

ALSO :: ON my homepage , the slider slide indicator seems to be out of center with the actual slider; and anything I do will not move it! It is cemented in place... If anyone has any ideas about that as well that would be great!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS fixed the issue:

```
.sidebar-left .sidebar, .sidebar-right .content {
   position: relative; 
   z-index: 0
 }

.sidebar-right .sidebar, .sidebar-left .content {
   position: relative; 
   z-index:99
 }
```

Keep in mind when you want to change the z-index of an element you have to make sure that the element is being positioned also. The element must have either: relative, absolute or fixed positioning in order to apply z-index.

Comment: Ahh thanks, the positioning seems to have been the culprit of it not moving. I see exactly why that would happen now. Thanks so much!